# How to merge consecutive date into one date?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a data that looks like the following :

```
invalid 43090   2017-08-01  2017-09-01
invalid 43090   2019-11-01  2019-12-01
invalid 43090   2019-12-01  2020-01-01
invalid 43090   2020-01-01  2020-02-01
invalid 43090   2020-02-01  2020-03-01
invalid 43090   2020-03-01  2020-04-01
invalid 43090   2020-04-01  2020-05-01
invalid 43090   2020-05-01  2020-06-01
invalid 43090   2020-06-01  2020-07-01
invalid 43090   2020-07-01  2020-08-01
```

i want to merge consecutive dates into one date as below:

```
invalid 43090 1 2017-08-01 2017-09-01
invalid 43090 2 2019-11-01 2020-08-01
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this in sql. I am using redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to identify the groupings.  Then aggregate:

```
select col1, col2, min(col3), max(col4)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_col4 = col3 then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by col1, col2
                  order by col3
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(col4) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as prev_col4
            from t
            ) t
     ) t
group by col1, col2, grp;
```